# How to achieve suggestions in input field

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I had come across a question how to achieve suggestions in the input field while typing for example (in browser url bar while we typing   first 3 to 4 letters it give suggestion if the url is correct we go with it else with single delete key press remove the suggested content). This need to be done with input field. Is this scenario is possible? Thanks.

Comment: It's very possible, but this feature is usually found as part of a larger framework like Angular or jQuery. Does your project already have a framework in place?

Comment: Yes I have completed with angular. Thanks @ChrisRiebschlager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a big range of possibilities here.

- If the contents of the list are static or easily generated via code, you can use a [native HTML `<datalist>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist).
- If you are wanting autocomplete in the form using the user's previously-provided data, you can just enable via the [`<input autocomplete>` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)
- If you're wanting far more customization, it's going to have to be some JavaScript that does the dirty work for you. Stack Overflow is not a good forum for getting library suggestions, but you should survey what's available in your current development stack.

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete suggestions are a very common Web Component. If you are using jQuery, you might want to try [this component](http://materializecss.com/forms.html#Autocomplete) published by Materialize. If you are using, say, Polymer, you might want to try [paper-autocomplete](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/ellipticaljs/paper-autocomplete). If you are using vanilla javascript, you could try typeahead, or something like this [autocomplete](https://goodies.pixabay.com/javascript/auto-complete/demo.html) library. Most other modern web frameworks will have some alternative. I wouldn't really recommend making one from scratch.